How to print size_t in CUDA printf()?
I have written a simple code in my CUDA kernel to check the correct of data:
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void testKernel(int *data, int n){
    size_t tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if(tid >= n) return;
    int v = data[tid];
    if(tid < 8) printf("%d: %d\n", tid, v);
}

int main(){
    int n = 128;
    auto h_data = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) h_data[i] = i;
    
    int *d_data;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_data, sizeof(int) * n);
    cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, sizeof(int) * n, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    
    testKernel<<<4, 32>>>(d_data, n);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    
    cudaFree(d_data);
    delete[] h_data;
    return 0;
}

The output of the above code is:
0: 0
1: 0
2: 0
3: 0
4: 0
5: 0
6: 0
7: 0

Obviously, the value of v is wrong. Then I modified the printf() to following:
printf("%lu: %d\n", tid, v);

And the output became correct, as follows:
0: 0
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: 4
5: 5
6: 6
7: 7

I think the reason is that I used a wrong format to print size_t type, but I don't know how this happend.
Besides, I have tried the same print format on CPU as follows:
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    size_t x = i;
    printf("%d: %d\n", x, h_data[i]);
}
/*
0: 0
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: 4
5: 5
6: 6
7: 7
*/

The result doesn't show any error although I use a wrong print format.

The proper format specifier for size_t is %zu.

The fact that sometimes or on some platform you get the expected result with the wrong specifier is not something you should rely on.

@wohlstad isn't size_t is just typedef of widest unsigned integer on the system? In that case, why is it wrong to use %lu?

@Moses %d that the OP used initially is wrong for sure. Rearding %lu I'm not 100%. But the documentation states that `%zu% should be used so I wouldn't use anything else.

@wohlstad it just seems a bit excessive for me to implement different specifier for size_t, when it's typedef.
Maybe it's just %u on some systems, I guess. In that case that's legit reason for using different specifier, so that you can write portable code.

@Moses It is rather defined in terms of how many bytes are addressable on the architecture (because it is used as the input to malloc etc., see here). It is possible that CUDA nowadays only supports platforms where %lu works for size_t, but who knows how it will look in the future.

In your specific example, tid has type size_t, therefore it cannot be printed using modifier %d. For the host version of printf, the appropriate qualifier for size_t would be %zu, however CUDA does not support it. Instead, you can use modifier %llu.
Example below:
__global__ void testKernel(int *data, int n){
    size_t tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if(tid >= n) return;
    int v = data[tid];
    if(tid < 8) printf("%llu: %d\n", tid, v);
}

I can confirm locally it works:
$ nvcc -o test test.cu
$ ./test
0: 0
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: 4
5: 5
6: 6
7: 7

